# Why we need binary translation in full virtualization?

Tags: virtualization

In hardware assisted virtualization, guest operation system runs on Ring 0, therefore it can run privileged instruction directly, am I right?

So why in full virtualization, VMM just won't run guest privileged instructions on Ring 0? why we need to translate them?

One reason which come into mind is different architectures (Different guest and host). is there anything more?

Answer (score 0):

> therefore it can run privileged instruction directly, am I right?

No, it is not completely true.  Privileged instructions would still attempt accessing privileged resources and thus cannot be allowed to see/change them behind VMM's back. Therefore they would trap. That is why a classic VMM executes guests with "trap-and-emulate" approach. The majority of guest instructions that are non-privileged are executed directly, and privileged ones trap and a emulated one-by-one. No translation, that is, transformation of large (>1 guest instruction) blocks of the code is required in any case.

Alternatively, a system resource can be made non-privileged and thus instructions accessing it turn into innocuous inside the virtualized environment.

> So why in full virtualization, VMM just won't run guest privileged instructions on Ring 0?

"Ring 0" is just a number, it does not mean much except that certain instructions receive new semantics: instead of faulting as they would do on the higher rings they are allowed to access system resources. But inside a VMM, they are not allowed to do that.

> why we need to translate them?

We don't, individual privileged instructions may be trapped and then emulated, or interpreted. "Translation" as a term has meaning only for blocks of instructions.

> One reason which come into mind is different architectures

That is a some sort of a degenerative case when 100% of guest instructions are "privileged", i.e. they will not behave as expected on chosen host. It does not make sense to attempt executing them directly, and interpreting each and every of them is too slow for many applications. This is where translation == compilation of bigger blocks starts making sense.

> is there anything more?

For Intel architecture, there are certain architectural idiosyncrasies that sometimes make the idea of (temporarily) disabling hardware-assisted virtualization and falling back to binary translation beneficial in terms of speed and correctness. However, I assume this topic to be part of another, more specific question, as the answer is quite involved and requires deep understanding of Intel VT-x.